# MyService.svc?wsdl shows 400 Bad Request IIS 7.5

Tags: web-services, wcf, iis-7.5

I'm on Windows 7 Ultimate x64 IIS 7.5
I have deployed the services to the web server and when I try them in IE like this: `MyService.svc?wsdl` I get the `400 "Bad Request" page`

I should get the description of the web service instead, anybody knows how to fix this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might need to do the following on the server:

```
cd c:\windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v3.0\Windows Communication Foundation\
```

followed by

```
ServiceModelReg -i
```

This should register the .SVC extension as a WCF service, if not already registered.

Comment: your answer is good, the web.config for my services was messed up

Answer (score 0):

Just an update: When using v4.0 on a 64-bit machine, you need to run go to

`c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework64\v4.0.30319\`

before running

> ServiceModelReg.exe -r

If you go to

`c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v4.0.30319\`

and do the same thing, we found that it doesn't work correctly and we keep getting:

> Unhandled Exception: System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException: The message could not be dispatched because the service at the endpoint address 'net.tcp://localhost/Elephant/Tiger.svc' is unavailable for the protocol of the address.